# How does LLVM handle the x86 flag register?

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, llvm, x86-64, llvm-ir

I am beginning to use llvm to play around with languages. After going through the kaleidoscope turtorial I am curious, how does the LLVM represent, manipulate the x86 flag register?

If there is an overflow, carry, or any other state, how do I get at that state in the IR and use it?

Comment: It doesn't directly model the flags register, languages in general don't.  You get it implicit with the instruction.  Carry is relevant for unsigned values, like llvm.uadd.with.overflow, overflow for signed values, like llvm.ssub.with.overflow, either or zero occur for comparison, icmp instruction.

Comment: How difficult would it be to extend the LLVM IR to handle all the eflags directly?

Comment: @ReverseFlow what for? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @AntonKorobeynikov I am playing around with assembly and it is annoying that LLVM does not model this directly for x86. My inquiry is a general inquiry, it seems rather  odd that such a basic fundamental construct in x86 needs a justification to be modeled.

Comment: LLVM-IR is a higher-level IR, not an assembly language.  So the flag result wouldn't be implicit, but yes ideally you'd have versions of operations that produce 2 results: a flag and an integer result.

Answer (score 2):

x86 flag & status register is pretty target-specific and certainly should not be modeled in LLVM IR – it is too low-level. The same concepts could be modeled otherwise in target-neutral manner via `llvm.uadd.with.overflow`, etc.

Also, remember that LLVM IR in general is in SSA form, so the instructions could be easily e.g. rearranged provided that the final values are the same. This operation, however, will not keep x86 flag register the same.